# Arial in front of font stack?

Tags: bug, design, fonts

The current font stack on the SO main page is `Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif`.

[image]

I'm confused why anyone would put Arial in front? Arial is generally considered poorly readable, and there are lots of good alternatives. E.g. Verdana or Tahoma are a big improvement and widely available.

Comment: Not sure if this is intentional, I'll go with a mistake and tag it as 'bug'

Comment: Interesting, [it wasn't like this a year ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286312/what-fonts-does-stack-overflow-use/286313#286313).

Comment: +1, I have a problem reading on it especially when there's double-f (i.e. ff). Just in case it's OS/browser-dependent, I'm using Windows 7 on Chrome 49.